# EF 6 Core prefix based on property of the entity in many-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two related entities:

```
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public class ApiResource : Entity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApiScope> ApiScopes { get; set; }
}
```

and related entity:

```
[Index(nameof(Name), IsUnique = true)]
public class ApiScope : Entity<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public ApiResource ApiResource { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to add prefix for ApiScope.Name based on ApiResource.Name. For example, if ApiResource.Name = "niceAPI", then for example ApiScope.Name = "niceAPI:test.read". Is this possible to do without manually adding prefix when creating ApiResource and ApiScope? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can modify your setter of `ApiScope.Name`. Something like

```cs
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set
    {
        string prefix = ApiResource.Name + ":";
        if (value.StartsWith(prefix))
            _name = value;
        else
            _name = prefix + value;
    }
}
```

But you should ensure `ApiResource` is set in advance.

Comment: I did controller for testing and it doesn't work: https://pastebin.com/6tbCjNbp, because ApiResource is always null. Why?

Comment: @Szyszka947 Try initializing `ApiResource` first.

Comment: I did it, but it still doesnt work

Comment: @Szyszka947 I've tested it by simple implementation. If you set `ApiResource` first as `new ApiScope() { ApiResource = apiRes, Name = "sth" }`, `ApiResource` has been set to `apiRes` when `Name` setter is called. When `ApiResource` is null, `apiRes` must be null.

Comment: I forgot to delete the incorrectly created ApiScope so it didn't work. Thank you!